# Is there a way to make an image follow cursor when you click on it HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to make a website where when you click on one image, the image follows your cursor. Then you can click on another image, and the other image will follow your cursor and the first image will stay still. This is the code I have so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>image follow</title>
    <style>
        body {
          background-image: url('a.png');
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-attachment: fixed; 
          background-size: 100% 100%;
        }
        </style>
        <link href="stylesheets/standard.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var init = true;
                $(document).on('click', function() {
                    $(this)[init?'on':'off']('mousemove', follow);
                    init = !init;
                });
    
                function follow(e) {
                    var xPos = e.pageX;
                    var yPos = e.pageY;
                    $("#imgLocation").html("The img is at: " + xPos + ", " + yPos);
                    $("#imgFollow").offset({
                        left: e.pageX,
                        top: e.pageY
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <img id="imgFollow" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:675px; LEFT:250px; WIDTH:100px; HEIGHT:100px" src="b.gif">
            <img id="imgFollow" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:675px; LEFT:450px; WIDTH:100px; HEIGHT:100px" src="a.jpg">

         </body>
</html>
```

The problem with this code is that when i click anywhere on the screen, the first image follows my cursor and when i try to click on the second image, it triggers the first image. how do I make it so that the image gets triggered by clicking in a certain area and not just anywhere on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Still looking through it, but picked up something right away -

```
 <img id="imgFollow" STYLE="" src="b.gif"> 
<img id="imgFollow" STYLE=" src="a.jpg">
```

You are assigning two different elements the same id, while ids should be unique per element. And by default any selector that selects based on id, will always select the First matching element it finds. So its always that same image that gets selected and follows the mouse.

Update - i think using event.target would be a far better way to select the image clicked on, rather than hard code it the way you have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>image follow</title>
    <style>
        body {
          background-image: url('a.png');
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-attachment: fixed; 
          background-size: 100% 100%;
        }
        </style>
        <link href="stylesheets/standard.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var init = true;
                var which="";
                $(document).on('click', function(event) {
                    $(this)[init?'on':'off']('mousemove', follow);
                    init = !init;
                    which = event.target.id;
                });
    
                function follow(e) {
                console.log(which);
                    var xPos = e.pageX;
                    var yPos = e.pageY;
                   $("#imgLocation").html("The img is at: " + xPos + ", " + yPos);
                    $("#"+which).offset({
                        left: e.pageX,
                        top: e.pageY
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <img id="imgFollow" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:675px; LEFT:250px; WIDTH:100px; HEIGHT:100px" src="b.gif" alt="b.gif">
            <img id="imgFollow2" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:675px; LEFT:450px; WIDTH:100px; HEIGHT:100px" src="a.jpg" alt="a.jpg">
      <img id="imgFollow3" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:375px; LEFT:450px; WIDTH:100px; HEIGHT:100px" src="z.jpg" alt="c.jpg">

         </body>
</html>
```